# Solving recurrence relation using Mathematica defined in a piecewise way

Tags: equation-solving, recursion

I have a recurrence relation defined as following:

```
RSolve[
 {
  p[0] == p0,
  p[1] == λ p[0]/μ,
  p[i + 1] == λ p[i]/(2 μ)
  },
 p[i], i
]
```

Note that the relation is differently for `i=1`, than for `i >= 1`. This yields the following error:

> DSolve::bvnul: For some branches of the general solution, the given boundary conditions lead to an empty solution. >>

When I use `Piecewise`, Mathematica just echos the input:

```
RSolve[
 {
  p[i + 1] == 
   Piecewise[{
     {p0, i == -1},
     {λ p[i]/μ, i == 0}, 
     {λ p[i]/(2 μ), i >= 1}}]
  },
 p[i], i
]
```

Also using `If` or `Condition` does not to work out.

Appreciate your help!

(Btw, this simple example can easily be solved by hand, but I would like to solve more complicated recursions involving piecewise definitions.)

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
RSolve[{
  p[1] == l p0/m,
  p[n + 1] == l /(2 m) p[n]},
  p[n], n]
 (*
  -> {{p[n] -> 2^(1 - n) (l/m)^n p0}}
 *)
```

(The overspecification of `p[0]` and `p[1]` is not to the taste of `RSolve`)

Another way:

```
k[0] = k0;
k[1] = l k[0]/m;
k[i_] := l k[i - 1]/(2 m) /; i > 1;
FindSequenceFunction[Table[k[i], {i, 1, 10}], n]
(*
-> 2^(1 - n) k0 (l/m)^n
*)
```

**Edit**

Reader, beware! As of v8.0, `RSolve` and `FindSequenceFunction` are both immature implementations (I think), and there a lot of cases where the output is just the input.